# Why is Google Keyboard incompatible with my HTC One X?

Tags: htc-one-x, gboard

I am unable to download [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) from Google Play on my HTC One X. It displays message that `This app is incompatible with your device.` No other information is displayed.

Android: 4.2.2
HTC Sense: 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with the default keyboard on the device?

Very odd though that would be marked incompatible for you since it is such a basic app and by Google. There are lots of ways developers can put filters on their apps however can even omit specific devices, countries, and carriers if they choose. There are few options you can try from here http://www.howtogeek.com/138500/

Comment: The default keyboard is fine. But I wanted to try out other options and Google Keyboard seemed like a nice one. Also my phone is unrooted.